# Updating SwiftUI view from an Objective C Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swiftui

I am not experienced with IOS development but have some basic understanding to work my way through it by reading docs and tutorials.

I wanted to call Objective C code from Swift and it worked fine, now I want to do the opposite and getting confused a bit.

Basically I first call an Objective C function in the action of a Button in SwiftUI, then I want that function to update an ObservedObject in the same SwiftUI view and want the view to re-render.

I have found and followed a few resources on that, which are

https://medium.com/@iainbarclay/adding-swiftui-to-objective-c-apps-63abc3b26c33

https://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Swift UI view looks like

```
class Foo : ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var baz = Foo();
    
    // Then access later as self.baz.bar as a parameter somewhere..
```

What would be the right way to update `bar` here ?

I did the correct build settings and added `@objc` tags and also imported `project_name-swift.h`.
Implemented and modified the example in
https://medium.com/@iainbarclay/adding-swiftui-to-objective-c-apps-63abc3b26c33 but got lost a bit because of my lack of experience in these environments.

Maybe somebody can push me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Let's assume my project name is `Project`.

Example code :
(A code very similar to this, compiles fine and the Objective C function calls, but on the swift side I get no output to console and the text doesn't render. I would really appreciate if you point my mistakes in this, since I get very rarely involved in iOS development.)

ContentView.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

var objectivec_class = Objectivec_Class()

class Foo : ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar = ""
}

@objc
class BridgingClass: NSObject {

    @ObservedObject var baz = Foo();
    @objc func updateString(_ content: NSMutableString) {
        print("This function is called from Objective C")
        self.baz.bar += content as String
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    /** 
     * This part seems fishy to me, 
     * It would have been better to inject the instance of Foo here in 
     * BridgingClass but, couldn't figure out how to.
     * This is only for showing my intention. 
     */
    @ObservedObject var baz = Foo();
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            objectivec_class.updateSwiftUi()
        })
        {
            Text(self.baz.bar)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Objective C Bridging Header,

Project-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "Objectivec_Class.h"
```

Objectivec_Class.h

```
#ifndef Objectivec_Class_h
#define Objectivec_Class_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Project-Swift.h"

@interface Objectivec_Class : NSObject

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString* stringWhichWillBeRendered;
    @property  BridgingClass *bridgingClass;

    - (id) init;

    - (void) updateSwiftUi;

@end

#endif /* Objectivec_Class_h */
```

Objectivec_Class.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Project-Swift.h"
#import "Objectivec_Class.h"

@implementation Objectivec_Class

    - (id)init{
        if( self = [super init] ){
            _stringWhichWillBeRendered  = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
            BridgingClass *bridgingClass = [BridgingClass new];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void) updateSwiftUi {
        NSString *thisWillBeRendered = @"Render this string.";
        [_stringWhichWillBeRendered appendString:thisWillBeRendered];
        [[self bridgingClass] updateString:_stringWhichWillBeRendered];
    }

@end
```

Comment: In general you should inject same instance of `foo` and in view and in objective-c object. If you show your code I would add a demo modifications on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
@objc
class BridgingClass: NSObject {

    var baz = Foo()  // here !!
...
```

and

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var baz = objectivec_class.bridgingClass.baz    // << this !!

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            objectivec_class.updateSwiftUi()
        })
        {
            Text(self.baz.bar)
        }
    }
}
```

Objectivec_Class.m

```
@implementation Objectivec_Class

    - (id)init{
        if( self = [super init] ){
            _stringWhichWillBeRendered  = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
            self.bridgingClass = [BridgingClass new]; // here !!

...
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it now but do you also have and idea why `print("This function is called from Objective C")` doesn't call also?

Comment: Objective C basically does not call the Swift function, it compiles and no runtime errors. Actually this is where I hit a dead end.

Comment: Also objectivec_class does not have a property called baz.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! And your answer helped so I will mark it as accepted but also to make things even more clear for other people, I will answer my own question also.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer my own question because I would also like to share how I have achieved this with the help of Asperi.

As a side subject, I had to switch back to the legacy build system because of the cyclic dependency errors I was getting from Xcode. This also implies me that there should be a better way to do all this :)

With that said and with the assumption that you did the prerequisites of bridging between Swift <-> ObjC both ways,

ContentView.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

var objectivec_class = Objectivec_Class()

class Foo : ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar = ""
}

@objc
class BridgingClass: NSObject {

    @ObservedObject var sharedObj = Foo()
    @objc func updateString(_ content: NSMutableString) {
        print("This function is called from Objective C (update String)")
        sharedObj.bar += content as String
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var stringToBeUpdated = ""

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            objectivec_class!.updateSwiftUi()
            self.stringToBeUpdated = objectivec_class!.bridgingClass.sharedObj.bar
        })
        {
            Text(self.stringToBeUpdated.isEmpty ? "tap me" : self.stringToBeUpdated)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Objective C Bridging Header,

Project-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "Objectivec_Class.h"
```

Objectivec_Class.h

```
#ifndef Objectivec_Class_h
#define Objectivec_Class_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// #import "Project-Swift.h"

/** Forward declaring the class and not including the "Project-Swift.h" file 
in this header is important if you are using Xcode's legacy build system */ 
@class BridgingClass;

@interface Objectivec_Class : NSObject

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString* stringWhichWillBeRendered;
    @property  BridgingClass *bridgingClass;

    - (id) init;

    - (void) updateSwiftUi;

@end

#endif /* Objectivec_Class_h */
```

Objectivec_Class.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Project-Swift.h"
#import "Objectivec_Class.h"

@implementation Objectivec_Class

    - (id)init{
        if( self = [super init] ){
            _stringWhichWillBeRendered  = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
            self.bridgingClass = [BridgingClass new];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void) updateSwiftUi {
        // Probably you did something there to update the string.
        NSString *thisWillBeRendered = @"New information appended to string";
        [_stringWhichWillBeRendered appendString:thisWillBeRendered];
        [[self bridgingClass] updateString:_stringWhichWillBeRendered];
    }

@end
```

Any comments are welcome, newbie here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) (KVO), and have your observable object register as observer for the property you want to monitor:

```swift
class Foo : ObservableObject {
    // bind the text to this
    @Published var bar = ""

    // no-one needs to know we delegate the work
    private let worker = Objectivec_Class()

    init() {
        worker.observe(\.stringWhichWillBeRendered, options: [.new]) { [weak self] obj, change in
            // the forced unwrap is safe here, due to the `options` parameter
            self?.bar = change.newValue!
        }
    }

    // call this from the button action
    func update() {
        worker.updateSwiftUi()
    }
}
```

KVO will make sure the observation handler will be called every time the monitored property changes. And in turn, the handler will keep the published value in sync with the Objective-C one, which means you can bind your UI elements to `bar` instead of knowing/caring about the internals of the (View)Model.

No need for an extra bridging (boilerplate) class, no need to change the Objective-C class just to accommodate the SwiftUI design.

You can apply this technique even to classes that you don't have control over, and thus cannot bed changed, e.g. ones from 3rd party libraries (just make sure the properties you want to monitor are KVO-compliant).